# Best way to program a tool that searches for combinations of regular expression subsections in a text file

Tags: python, regex

I have a large text file with each line being a unique concept. There are probably only a small number of patterns to each line.

If I want to run through the text file and find common patterns between the lines for use with later regular expression extract of each sub-section of the line; what would be the best way or are there any existing tools? I prefer Python.

So a line might follow these patterns:

```
(1 to 5 alpha letters)(,)(space)(Sentence)
(word)(.)(space)(Sentence)(Sentence)
(word)(number)(.)(space)(Sentence)(Sentence)
(word)(!)(space)(Sentence)(Sentence)
```

I might not know about (!) for example.

Basically it should extract a list of regular expressions that in total cover each possible line, but with defined building blocks; like (1 to 5 alpha letters)(Sentence)(anything not covered by the building blocks)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an algorithm for [pattern recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition) and/or [data mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining) which are very complex subfields of artificial intelligence.

I suggest that you either pick up a book on the subject or try to solve your problem a different way.